# ¿como puedo insertar un dato del tipo date a MySql desde un formulario PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

necesito de su ayuda, estoy haciendo unos formularios para agregar datos a la base de datos en MySQL y al registrarse los datos del tipo Date los guarda como 0000-00-00, tengo entendido que hay un formato pero no entendí muy bien como funciona.
En la imagen esta el formulario, y quiero insertar estas fechas a la Base de datos que que corresponden a el inicio de temporada y el final de temporada para la siembra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo aquí el código que uso para poder insertar los valores a la base de datos.

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `periodo_temporadas`(`PeriodoID`,`Definicion`, `InicioTemporada`, `FinalTemporada`) VALUES ('".$PeriodoID."','".$Definicion."','".$InicioTemporada."','".$FinalTemporada."')");
```

(Nota: el InicioTemporada y FinalTemporada son del tipo Date, Definición y Periodo ID son del tipo Varchar)

Lo que necesito es por si no me quedo claro es insertar las fechas porque  las guarda como 0000-00-00 y no encuentro la forma :(
Espero puedan ayudarme y muchas gracias por su aporte

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta realmente, por lo que puedo entender necesitas formatear una fache a YYYY-MM-DD al insertar esos datos, php tiene la siguiente función la cual puedes utilizar formatear fechas, horas (…)
`date('Y-m-d', strtotime(fecha))`

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder , es que quiero hacer unas inserciones desde un formulario con PHP a una base de datos en MySQL. Los demás valores me los guarda bien pero los que son fechas los guarda algo así 0000-00-00 , quiero  saber de que manera puede arreglarse

Comment: Esto es muy, MUY vulnerable a SQL injection. Lee sobre cómo usar PDO.

Comment: si, entiendo, es que aún soy algo nuevo en php

Comment: Haz un `echo $InicioTemporada;` y un `echo $FinalTemporada;` y dinos cómo están llegando esos datos al servidor para poder ayudarte. Sin ver el formato de las cadenas que estás recibiendo no podemos decirte qué tienes que hacer para crear una fecha válida.

Comment: Ya logre corregir el problema, estaba mal el orden al crear la fecha la cual es yyyy/mm/dd

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré la solución, al parecer no estaba escribiendo bien la fecha la cual el orden es yyyy/mm/dd y pues con ese orden ahora si se registran en la base de datos(no sé porque no me daba)

Aqui estan mis fechas agregadas correctamente:
[image: Fechas creadas en Mysql]

Aqui esta una captura de como esta mi formulario y de como ahora si esta bien el orden para que se registre la fecha
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]